# when i select in or out something in filter or selected some think in selected box it return the login page

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm want to stay in page and not return in login page,How can i do

[image]

This is login code:

```py
if selected == "Annual Report":
    username_placeholder = st.empty()
    password_placeholder = st.empty()
    username = username_placeholder.text_input("Username")
    password = password_placeholder.text_input("Password", type="password")
    login_button_placeholder = st.empty()
    if login_button_placeholder.button("Log in"):
        if username == VALID_USERNAME and password == VALID_PASSWORD:
            # ลบช่องที่ใส่ username และ password ออก
            username_placeholder.empty()
            password_placeholder.empty()           
            login_button_placeholder.empty()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.